# How to create linked dropdowns sharing a single list and ensure each value can only be selected in one dropdown?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to create a group of dropdowns using  knockout out that allow users to select up to 3 values from a list e.g. colours. The list starts as:- Red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet

```
DropDown 1 - Select any of the 7
DropDown 2 - Select any of the 6 remaining
Dropdown 3 - Select any of the 5 remaining
```

If the user goes back and changes DropDown 1 to something they should only have the choices of the other remaining colours (and the one in Drop Down 1). If they then change it, I would be able to go to dropdown 2 or 3 and change that to the value that used to be in 1.

I think I need an initial array containing the 7 items, then I need an observable per dropdown. The 3 obseravables would have to be based on the initial data and excluding the selected of the other three dropdowns. I am really struggling with this. I can't even come close to implementing it.

Is this even possible or an appropriate use for Knockout or should I just look at JS with an onChange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible in Knockout. And there's probably 10 ways to do it. I've come up with one way here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/wfW97/

Here's the code for reference:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'];
    self.selections = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.colors, function() {
        self.selections.push(ko.observable());
    });
    self.selfAndUnselectedColors = function(index) {
        var selfColor = self.selections[index]();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.colors, function(color) {
            return color === selfColor || !ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.selections, function(sel) {
                return color === sel();
            });
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And HTML:

```
<div data-bind="repeat: colors.length">
    <select data-bind="options: selfAndUnselectedColors($index), optionsCaption: 'select a color', value: selections[$index]"></select>
</div>​
```

I'm using my [repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding plugin to create the repeated select elements, but you could use some other method if you wanted.

Comment: That was great. Really appreciate your help with this and the great work on Knockout! I just wanted 3 so just changed the repeat. The rest of it is perfect. This will be really helpful in lots of Apps. It would be great to have Knockout recipes website and collect all of these random things together. There are so many really useful things it can do.

Comment: I changed it to use index for select list. I was wondering if you had any idea how I can set an initial value for each of the dropdowns? http://jsfiddle.net/GraemeMiller/BTHHS/1/