# Updating dropdownlist based on previous dropdownlists

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Apart of my MVC3 project, we designed a page with 3 security questions and answers respectively (around 10 in the dropdownlist). The questions can be selected from the dropdownlist and the answer will be filled in the textbox below it.

Design:
Let us say, if the user selected question1 as ( 1 of 10) questions. The second drop down should show only 9 questions(skipping the first question). and in the same way the 3rd question will have only 8 options.

In the same way, if the user changes the index to 0 (which says select question). That question, which he removed should appear in the other dropdownlists.

Please help in designing this page. I tried using JQuery, which didn't help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(function() {
    // Load all the dropdowns
    $('[id^=select]').html($('.template').html());
    // This array Holds the Objects
    var arr = ['select1', 'select2', 'select3'];
    // Declare a array where you store the selections
    var arrSelect = {
        'select1': '0',
        'select2': '0',
        'select3': '0'
    };

    $('select').on('change', function() {
        var currID = $(this).prop('id');
        // Set the Current selection
        arrSelect[currID] = $(this).val();
        // Iterate Thru each dropdown 
        $.each(arr, function(i) {
            var temp = arrSelect[arr[i]];
            // Clone the template
            var $clone = $('.template').clone();
            // Remove Questions from template based on selected
            // values in other select's
            $.each(arrSelect, function(index, value) {
                if (value != 0 && value != temp) {
                    $clone.find('option[value=' + value + ']').remove();
                }
            });
            // If not Current select rewrite its 
            // contents of the select
            if (arr[i] != currID) {
                //console.log('#' + arr[i] + ' :: ' + $clone.html());
                $('#' + arr[i]).html('').html($clone.html());
                $('#' + arr[i]).val(temp);
            }
        });
    });
})​
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/a3yrQ/)

Comment: Know it is an old answer, but thanks a lot for this. Helped me so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). Basically create a JavaScript Viewmodel that returns the available questions.

I had a [similar requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092291/how-to-create-linked-dropdowns-sharing-a-single-list-and-ensure-each-value-can-o) and the following worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/wfW97/

Here's the code for reference:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.colors = ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'];
    self.selections = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.colors, function() {
        self.selections.push(ko.observable());
    });
    self.selfAndUnselectedColors = function(index) {
        var selfColor = self.selections[index]();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.colors, function(color) {
            return color === selfColor || !ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.selections, function(sel) {
                return color === sel();
            });
        });
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And HTML:

```
<div data-bind="repeat: colors.length">
    <select data-bind="options: selfAndUnselectedColors($index), optionsCaption: 'select a color', value: selections[$index]"></select>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and the link that provided to test. Really appreciated. But I don't have much knowledge on the Knockout,So, I am just using the JQuery script that was provided by  sushanthreddy.

Comment: No problem. Each to their own. I tend to use Knockout when the screen view is complex with various dependencies.